# Binance "Event Time" vs "Trade time"

Tags: api, trading, binance

I am looking at the Binance Websocket Stream and have a question about Event time and Trade time.  If this is raw trade information, how can there be 2 different times for a "Trade"?  What is the "Event Time"?

From the github API docs:

**Trade Streams**

The Trade Streams push raw trade information; each trade has a unique buyer and seller.

Stream Name: @trade

Payload:

```
{
  "e": "trade",     // Event type
  "E": 123456789,   // Event time
  "s": "BNBBTC",    // Symbol
  "t": 12345,       // Trade ID
  "p": "0.001",     // Price
  "q": "100",       // Quantity
  "b": 88,          // Buyer order Id
  "a": 50,          // Seller order Id
  "T": 123456785,   // Trade time
  "m": true,        // Is the buyer the market maker?
  "M": true         // Ignore.
}
```

Comment: There is also an OrderId which always come in the right order, but TradeTime is not always in the right order, meaning you can get a bigger order with a lower trade time.

Answer (score 14):

The **"T"** or **"Trade time"** is the time of the transaction in milliseconds. I recommend using this time.

The **"E"** or **"Event time"** is the time value is inherent only to the sockets. It is associated with creating a socket object.

Usually "Event time" more then "Trade time" and the difference between these values is only a few milliseconds. Less than 30-40 milliseconds. Sometimes "Event time" less then "Trade time".